# pdf viewer with fill of rectangle objects

Tags: pdf, textbox, rectangles

Many PDFs have white rectangles or long underlines and are meant to be printed and filled by hand. I want to fill them digitally.

I've searched a lot, even in the Python code for a simple viewer with the annotation option, because no one does a simple thing: use the existing rectangles as a reference to the text box area of the annotation or set the leading in the text box annotation .

All tools force you to write many lines by repositioning the text box for each one. An exception is Ms Edge but she doesn't have the leading option and therefore busts.
When I import the PDF into libreoffice draw, I can dblclick on the white rectangle and write some text. But its import strains many pdfs.

If anyone has any suggestions in the meantime, I would appreciate it.
Thank you

Actually Microsoft Edge is the smartest tool:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIwqv.png)

Comment: Thanks, I improved the content (hope).

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Free Text is primarily an editor function. Most PDF viewers that can annotate will default to basic text insert. Xpdf free viewer has no annotation editor.

[image]

Possibly the most lightweight PDF viewer, that can fill forms and add text, is MuPDF.

[image]

Comment: +1 but unfortunatelly MuPDF is limited to annotation of 6 lines. Sono Microsoft Edge is actually the most smart tool.